# Some special Metric on R

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

Apart from usual and discrete metric is there a metric on R which satisfy:                   d(x, y) = d(x+r , y+r) where x and y are any real no. and r is arbitary real no.

Similarly is there a metric on R which satisfy: d(x, y) = d(x.r , y.r) for any real no. r except than zero.

Comment: How about the sum of the discrete and usual metrics :-)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.
Metrics that satisfy $d(x+r,y+r)=d(x,y)$:
There are many metrics of this kind, as remarked by other users.
Also the sum of any such metrics still has the property.

2.
Metrics that satisfy $d(xr,yr)=d(x,y)$:
There is such a metric on $(0,\infty)$, namely $d(x,y)=|\log(x)-\log(y)|$.

There are also such metrics on $\mathbb R$, and something can be said about them.
The value of $d(0,x)$ is independent of $x$; let us call this constant $c$.
The values of the metric are bounded by $2c$ due to the triangle inequality.
Because of the scaling invariance there is a function $\phi:\mathbb R\setminus\{0,1\}\to(0,2c)$ such that $d(a,b)=\phi(a/b)$ when $a\neq b$.
Starting from the triangle inequality, one can show various inequalities for $\phi$, but there are possibilities left.

For example, $\phi\equiv1$ (discrete metric) or $\phi(x)=1$ for $x<0$ and $\phi(x)=\min\{1,|\log(x)|\}$ when $x>0$.
The second one is not discrete.

Comment: Why would $d(0,x)$ be independent of $x$? This is not true with the usual metric which is translation invariant.

Comment: @copper.hat, for any $x\neq0$ we have $d(0,x)=d(0\times x^{-1},x\times x^{-1})=d(0,1)$ by the assumed scaling invariance.

Comment: You might want to clarify that you are answering the second part of the question.

Comment: @copper.hat, good point. I'll edit.

Comment: @Joonas Ilmavirta One minute: hw rd(1,2)=d(r,2r) I have not assumed this one. I have just said d(x, y) = d(x.r, y.r) And this is true in case of discrete metric. But I want metric other than discrete

Comment: @Sushil, true. I edited my answer accordingly. There is a nondiscrete solution to the second part.

Answer (score 1):

How about $d(x,y)=\max\{1,|y-x|\}$ or $d(x,y)=\frac{|y-x|}{1+|y-x|}$?